# Python not recognizing wheel manually installed

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

Some colleague gave me a wheel file. I used pip to install it:

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

When i run

```
pip list
```

the package is displayed just fine. Also, there is a folder with the package in C:\WinPython2_7_10_1\python-2.7.10\Lib\site-packages

The problem is that I could not import it in the code. PyDev in eclipse does not find it.

```
from some-package import *
```

gives me an error

What is happening? Is it with my installation or my colleague generated an wheel with an error?

I tried to reload PyDev Interpleter, change names, everything, no sucess.

obs:
I am using WinPython 2.7.10 with PyDev

Comment: Run `python -vvv` and it will print out import debug diagnostics.

Comment: Also do `import sys ; print sys.path`

Comment: print sys.path correctly shows "(..) site-packages folder

Comment: python -vvv shows a bunch of information, but I could find anything related specifically to my package

Comment: FYI `some-package` is not valid Python module name as they cannot contain dashes.

Comment: actually the name is calculateWheel     :-)

Comment: Does it work if you run the script with the command `C:\WinPython2_7_10_1\python-2.7.10\bin\Python.exe myscript.py`

Comment: SOLVED!  It was a problem with the wheel package...  The script calculateWheel.py was not inside a package...  It was installed in site-packes/calculateWheel.py...     So it was not visible from import command